# Configure multiple nodejs servers to share node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a VPS that I use to host client sites I build using nodeJS + Express. `npm` is my package manager and before I really knew what I was doing, I had built four sites each using modules installed with `npm install foo --save` (omitting the `-g` flag).

I'm now seeing that four node servers sitting behind nginx are taking up just under 50% of my (allocated) 1GB RAM. They're quite basic websites so I can't help but wonder if there is a way I can "rebuild" them to share common modules from a global install... When I ran `htop` this morning I noticed that each instance of a node server seems to have a corresponding `npm` instance running and each is using a couple of % points of available memory. Will sharing common modules be more efficient like I think it will be? If so, how do I reconfigure these sites to use shared modules?

My existing directory structure is setup similar to this:

```
sites/
  -- site1/
    --node_modules/
  -- site2/
    --node_modules/
...
```

The biggest concern here is minimizing any downtime on these sites, second concern is maximizing performance.

Comment: I'm _fairly_ sure that `-g` won't make any difference since the node processes run in their own process space, most likely not sharing any state.

Comment: I should also add that they typically share a large number of common modules for things like Stylus, Jeet, Rupture, and Nib.

Comment: If you put the package.json at the same level as `/sites`, then `/site1`, `/site2`, etc will all share the packages. BUT, you'll end up needing refactoring for packages like mongoose which share state across files, and you'd need to refactor any npm scripts you use.

Comment: I don't think it would actually matter anything performancewise. Sharing the files doesn't mean they only have to be loaded once. It only affects the space used on your drive, not the memory used.

Comment: @DoXicK I wondered about that as well. The storage space isn't an issue at all at the moment so perhaps it's not worth the effort?

Comment: nah, wouldn't do it. only way you are going to get performance gains is when you tie everything up into the same process, which is a lot harder to do than just "refactoring"